# Alert Dialog Box Error (The type new View.OnClickListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method View.OnClickListener.onClick(View))

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want the alert box to be displayed with a **OK button** after clicking the button submit which is 'sb' in the below code but it says:

- The method `setNeutralButton(int, DialogInterface.OnClickListener)` in the type `AlertDialog.Builder` is not applicable for the arguments

  `(String, new View.OnClickListener(){})`
- The type `new View.OnClickListener(){}` must implement the inherited abstract method    `View.OnClickListener.onClick(View)`

**Could Someone please tell me what is wrong with my code?**

```
private void setClickListenerOnButton_sb() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        sb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        con);
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Forgot Password Response");
                alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Password sent to your Email Id, Please Login Now");
                alertDialogBuilder.setNeutralButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: you should prefix the OnClickListeners, like this "DialogInterface.OnClickListener" and "View.OnClickListener". And also make sure that you have not a custom class called "View", if it's the case, then replace the type of the parameter "View" of the onClick method with android.view.View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code from

```
alertDialogBuilder.setNeutralButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {
```

To

```
alertDialogBuilder.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
```